# How to use the GDB debugger with OpenMolcas?

Tags: python, programming, fortran, open-molcas

I would like to follow how some variables are changing during an OpenMolcas calculation, and adding `WRITE` statements has become too tedious. I've compiled with the `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` option:

```
cmake ../OpenMolcas_HPQC_LEVEL -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
make -j8
```

I've set the `PATH` accordingly:

```
pymolcas
> MOLCAS has been found at /home/nike/build_OpenMolcas_HPQC_LEVEL_Debug
```

Attempts to use gdb have failed, for example:

```
gdb --args pymolcas
> "/home/nike/build_OpenMolcas_HPQC_LEVEL_Debug/pymolcas": not in executable format: file format not recognized
```

When searching the word "debug" on the [Molcas forum](https://molcasforum.univie.ac.at/search.php?search_id=792551514) I got about 29 results, but most of them were about running calculations in parallel (I am not), or just had the word `debug` in the post because it was part of the `CMAKE` output, even if the post had nothing to do with debugging. The most relevant results that I found there were:

- The `-D DEBUG_DEFS=_DEVEL_` was recommended [here](https://molcasforum.univie.ac.at/viewtopic.php?pid=2401#p2401) but that was in the context of turning errors into warnings (which is not what I'm trying to do).
- [This post](https://molcasforum.univie.ac.at/viewtopic.php?pid=1873#p1873)) includes an output file that says "To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line option", but it's in the context of LUSCUS and `pymolcas -h` suggests that `--sync` isn't an option for `pymolcas`.

I also searched the documentation, and found that there's a `MOLCAS_DEBUGGER` environment variable but running `export MOLCAS_DEBUGGER=gdb` before the above `gdb` command leads to the same error (and I assume this environment variable affects the running of `molcas` rather than `pymolcas`). The word "debug" shows up a few times in the [Documentation PDF](https://molcas.gitlab.io/OpenMolcas/Manual.pdf) (18 times to be exact) but mainly in the context of printing more output, in addition to the afformentioned `CMAKE` build type and the `MOLCAS_DEBUGGER` variable

The word debug appears another 71 times in the [CMakeLists file](https://github.com/Molcas/OpenMolcas/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) but rather than going through every possibility there, if there's perhaps a set of *instructions* on how to use `gdb` with OpenMolcas (perhaps in the documentation), it would be helpful if you could let me know them!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pymolcas` runs each program as a separate process, so you need to insert `gdb` before each individual program call, and not before `pymolcas`. This is what `MOLCAS_DEBUGGER` is supposed to achieve. Try:

```
MOLCAS_DEBUGGER=gdb pymolcas ...
```

PS: For OpenMolcas-specific questions you can use https://openmolcas.zulipchat.com/

Comment: Thanks! I've now tried `export MOLCAS_DEBUGGER=gdb pymolcas` but am not sure what the `...` is supposed to represent? Also, this sounds like I shouldn't call `gdb` with `gdb --args pymolcas`. Do you have any recommendation how I should run it?

Comment: The `...` means whatever arguments you'd normally pass to `pymolcas`.

Comment: I generally just do `pymolcas 800.input -f`, but doing `export MOLCAS_DEBUGGER=gdb pymolcas 800.input -f` would give `-bash: export: `-f': not a valid identifier`. Also if I just do `export MOLCAS_DEBUGGER=gdb pymolcas` then `gdb` followed by `r < 800.input` or `r pymolcas 800.input -f` gdb complains about not knowing what to execute. So I wonder how to get `pymolcas 800.input -f` running in debug mode?

Comment: `-f` redirects the output to a file, so you don't want to use it for interactive debugging. Try simply `MOLCAS_DEBUGGER=gdb pymolcas 800.input` (and without `export`).

Comment: Beautiful, it worked!

Answer (score 2):

The following eventually worked for me, especially after [Jellby's most recent comment](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/10095/how-do-i-use-gdb-with-openmolcas#comment21417_10096):

### Compiling:

```
cmake ../OpenMolcas_HPQC_LEVEL -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
make -j8
export PATH=$PATH:/home/nike/build_OpenMolcas_HPQC_LEVEL
```

### Debugging:

```
MOLCAS_DEBUGGER=gdb pymolcas inputFile.input
```

Unlike some programs, in which you might run something like `gdb --args ~/path/to/program/level.exe` followed by `run < inputFile.input` to have `level.exe` run with the input file `inputFile.input`, the `run` command is not used at this stage because the above command involving `MOLCAS_DEBUGGER` will invoke Molcas to **start running immediately** with the input file `inputFileinput`. After parsing the input file it will start running `gdb` before running the "module" or "program" within Molcas that your input file wishes to invoke. In my case the first line of the input file was `&LEVEL` so after parsing and printing (in the command window) the input file, it printed:

```
--- Start Module: level at Tue Dec 13 07:19:04 2022 ---
GNU gdb (Gentoo 9.1 vanilla) 9.1
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://bugs.gentoo.org/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from /home/nike/build_OpenMolcas_HPQC_LEVEL_Debug/bin/level.exe...
(gdb)
```

At the `gdb` prompt I was able to set my breakpoint and to run the "module" or "program":

```
(gdb) b level.f:10
(gdb) r
```

This was the output:

```
Starting program: /home/nike/build_OpenMolcas_HPQC_LEVEL_Debug/bin/level.exe 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/gentoo/2020/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".

()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()

                                               &LEVEL

                                   only a single process is used
                       available to each process: 2.0 GB of memory, 1 thread?
                                             pid: 34832
()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()


Breakpoint 1, level (rc=7844255429672472576) at /home/nike/OpenMolcas_HPQC_LEVEL/src/level/level.f:76
76        NLEV2= -1
(gdb)
```

which is exactly what I was hoping to achieve

### Summary:

Compile with the above commands, then debug/run with `MOLCAS_DEBUGGER=gdb pymolcas inputFile.input` and you should then be able to use `gdb` in the way that you're familiar.